# Distorted ViewPager rounded circle item

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-viewpager

I'm trying to make initial/start pages, which should introduce main features of an application to an user.
My code is based on this tutorial: http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-circle-style-example/ . Actually, I included the whole code several times seperately (to be sure if I haven't made an mistake) to my app, but it still came up with an error. I don't know which specific code snippet to post, because I don't know to what it's related for (if you have an idea, please, say, and I will post the code immediately). I'm posting a part of gradle file (I have a thought, that it's related with a support-v4 library)and rounded-circle layout:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.0@aar'
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
    android:startColor="@color/white"
    android:endColor="@color/white"
    android:angle="0"
    />
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"  android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/l_blue" android:width="1dp" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Here are screenshots from various apps: demo(how rounded circles should look like) and the one, to which I would like to transfer it: See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ry9U.jpg
I would be very grateful for helping me out. Thanks in advance